# Computer shuts down unexpectedly like been unplugged

Tags: windows-7, boot, power-supply, shutdown

My stationary computer keeps shutting down after some time without any error messages. It just shuts down instantly like it's been unplugged.When pressing the Power button it doesn't turn on, unless i unplug it from power outlet and then plug it back. Reinstalled two diferrent versions of Windows 7(x64) and nothing changed. However, when i'm in BIOS it doesn't shut down. Tried:

-Memory Testing - no errors

-Scanned for viruses - no viruses(using Malware Anti-Malware)

-Processor doesn't overheat

-Cleaned all the dust inside the Motherboard(including videocard,ram,processor, power supply)

Also I haven't experienced this issue when I booted Windows 7(x64) in Safe Mode.
Here's a screenshot of my system specifications.

[image: My system Summary:]

Comment: what exactly are you doing when it shuts down?

Comment: It shuts down independently. There isn't a specific moment when it shuts down.

Answer (score 2):

You have added [power-supply](/questions/tagged/power-supply), and frankly this is what should be tested in the first place in such cases (no pun intended). Borrow one from a friend, and see if it's yours who is a culprit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/587116)

Comment: This does provide an answer to the question. This answer directs OP to go and diagnose his PC with a borrowed PSU. Nothing can be added.

Comment: How can the PSU be the problem if my computer doesn't shut down when i'm in BIOS or Safe Mode?

Comment: Modern PSUs are complex devices, which work in different modes. Once you are in BIOS, PSU's wattage may be the one, and once you are in OS it may be other. Even some sporadic maintenance process, which consumes 100% of CPU time for a little while may cause PSU to fail and thus computer to unexpectedly shut down. It definitely looks like an electric problem to me, thus it is caused either by a PSU (85%) or a motherboard itself (I bet 15% on it). By the way UPS also is a way to go to mitigate wall electricity problem, in case your current is "unstable".

Comment: And regarding the Safe Mode. In this mode all drivers aren't usually loaded (just the generic ones are loaded), and some parts of OS are offline, so it is possible, for example, that your graphics card demands a lot of power from PSU when its proprietary driver is loaded (Normal Mode) and significantly less power with a generic driver (in Safe Mode). Just guessing, but you should swap components around to find the root of the problem. Start with a PSU.

Comment: sleep states have bee know to cause this, which wouldn't happen in the BIOS presumably (though I don't think an athlon has the "Haswell C6 PSU" problem). A failing power supply may work under idle and light load conditions, but "sag" enough when e.g. starting a fullscreen 3d game that the motherboard shuts down. etc Both of these have happened to me, and both of these things were due a PSU problem

Comment: For example in my GPU scenario, I found GPU stress tester which would turn off the computer instantly on 100% of runs, and then I tested with a borrowed PSU as @TranslucentCloud suggested.

Comment: I tested the computer with a borrowed PSU. The issue still persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Now it's time to test HDD/SSD and if they are not the cause, the motherboard itself.

Comment: I have 1 HDD and 1 SSD: one on which the OS is held, and another for personal purposes. The second had some bad sectors which where "fixed" by using the chkdsk /f /r command. The first one doesn't have any bad sectors or errors. I borrowed another SSD from a friend and he had WIndows XP SP3 on it. WHen i connected that one and booted from it, the computer DIDN'T SHUT DOWN. Now i'm clearly confused

Comment: @Yorik Tried the gpu stress tester and the videocard is working fine. The temperature doesn't grow fast and it keeps up at 92-93 degrees while being stressed for over an hour.

Comment: So you've found out that it's your SSD which caused a problem?

Comment: @TranslucentCloud I'm not quite sure about it. After some intense googling, I then used the Windows Verifier tool to scan for driver errors. After a restart, my windows activation went off. I think that stopped the Shutting Down issue for a while. Later i tried to reinstall the OS, and the problem persisted again, unfortunately during the installation process. I disconnected the "suspicious SSD", but it didn't help.

Comment: Then the last thing to check up is a motherboard itself.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud I don't really think it's the motherboard, since the problem would have occured with Windows XP SP3 after i connected the borrowed SSD. But i will try to test it in the all posibile for me ways. If you have any other suggestions, feel free to write them.

Comment: The suggestions are already written: you need to check up the PC with freshly installed OS, swap PSU, system drive, GPU, memory, motherboard at last. Before testing the mobo, answer these questions: did you update BIOS/UEFI? Was memory checked with memtest?

Comment: After a few tests, i've come to the following results:
- Computer shuts down in Linux Mint Serena and Windows 7;
- Computer DOESN't shut down while in Windows XP SP3 ;
- Tried to swap PSU, the problem didn't disappear;
- Stress tested GPU,CPU and Power Supply with OCCT and all didn't cause shutdowns;
- Memory was checked with memtest and no errors we're found;
- BIOS hasn't been upgraded and i don't see the necesity of doing it;
- The motherboard doesn't have any signs of blown capacitors or any other damage;

Comment: If BIOS/UEFI update is available, you will certainly want to install it, since it may resolve some mysterious bugs.

Comment: BIOS has the latest updates. Just checked for BIOS updates.

Comment: Okay, then the last part of concern is the motherboard, given the fact you successfully tested your drives. Swap it and check if this helps.